# The logic behind Skeletal Animation in OpenGL

Tags: animation

What are the bone weight, bone influences, joints, offset and local matrices used for ? There is no certain article on the internet that explains the logic well. I still don't know if every bone has a different model that is combined later with the other models. Or how to handle these matrices, how to set bones, combine and skin them... I will be glad if you can share any articles or your knowledge about skeletal animation in opengl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of these terms will differ betweens implementations. Rather than try to provide concrete definitions, I'd prefer to give a very rough overview of how skinning works, as I think that's what you're asking.

Also, this is not particularly GL specific...

The main idea is that you take a polygonal model and attach it to a skeleton. Each vertex in the model is assigned to one or more bones. A bone, in this context, is really just a transformation, though they are typically visualised as a skeleton, as the bones are usually authored in a hierarchy and will naturally resemble an actual skeleton.

A 'joint' may just mean 'bone', or in other contexts may in fact refer to how two bones are connected and articulated...

As the bones are hierarchical, they will have 'local' transforms which describe their transformation relative to a parent. At runtime the transforms will usually be concatenated such that they are all in the same space.

The assigning of vertices to bones is done using weights. Weights will *usually* add up to 1 for each vertex. Weights can be automatically assigned by proximity to a bone, but will typically be hand-adjusted by an artist. Often they are 'painted' onto the 3D model using a tool in the art package.

At runtime, vertices are transformed by each bone they are influenced by, and the final vertex position is the weighted average of the result of those different transforms. How that weighted average is calculated can vary, but that's the general approach.

However for runtime applications, it is usually important to keep the number of different bones influencing a vertex to a minimum, and there may well be an upper limit which is relatively small; 4, perhaps. So instead of providing each vertex with a weight for every bones in the skeleton, it is common to provide a fixed number of joint indices, with corresponding weights.

Note that you generally do not do anything with texture coordinates when skinning, but you will almost certainly have to recalculate normals and possibly tangent vectors. Again, how to do that can vary between implementations.

Comment: thanks for your answer, sorry for my late reply. i have a question about these local and absolute transform matrices, are they the same as we customly generate in opengl just like in this link : http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html (OpenGL Transformation Matrix) ?